# How can we expose Micronaut beans into an exsting Spring app

Tags: spring, micronaut

How can we do incremental migration of Spring app to Micronaut ?
I am looking for away to migrate Spring Beans to Micronaut.
I tried to consume a Micronaut bean from a Spring app following the docs but it is not wokring

My example test:
https://github.com/luistrigueiros/micronaut-expose-spring-beans/blob/master/src/test/groovy/example/ConsumeBeanSpec.groovy

## [ConsumeBeanSpec.groovy](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/luistrigueiros/micronaut-expose-spring-beans/master/src/test/groovy/example/ConsumeBeanSpec.groovy)

```
import groovy.util.logging.Slf4j
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration
import spock.lang.Specification

import javax.inject.Inject

@Slf4j
@ContextConfiguration(classes = [Config])
class ConsumeBeanSpec extends Specification {
    @Inject
    ConsumerBean consumerBean

    def "should be able to do something"(){
        expect:
            consumerBean.doSomething()
    }

}
```

The current stack trace error:
    ... 36 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'example.ExposedBean' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1509)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1104)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1065)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:815)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:721)
    ... 54 common frames omitted

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext

```
at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:125)
at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:108)
at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:117)
at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:83)
at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:246)
at org.spockframework.spring.SpringTestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(SpringTestContextManager.java:49)
at org.spockframework.spring.SpringInterceptor.interceptSetupMethod(SpringInterceptor.java:42)
at org.spockframework.runtime.extension.AbstractMethodInterceptor.intercept(AbstractMethodInterceptor.java:28)
at org.spockframework.runtime.extension.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:87)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
```

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'consumerBean' defined in file [C:\tools\micronaut.io\study\micronaut-expose-spring-beans\out\production\classes\example\ConsumerBean.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'example.ExposedBean' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:729)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:192)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1274)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1131)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:541)

Comment: It would be helpful to post some error messages or console output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have sent a PR to https://github.com/luistrigueiros/micronaut-expose-spring-beans/pull/1 which allows your test to pass.

As the javadocs at https://docs.micronaut.io/1.0.0.M1/api/io/micronaut/spring/beans/MicronautBeanProcessor.html, `MicronautBeanProcessor` only processes singleton beans.

That is imposed at https://github.com/micronaut-projects/micronaut-core/blob/0108642b11d0c6d7f11bcffc85b357e823c98d42/spring/src/main/java/io/micronaut/spring/beans/MicronautBeanProcessor.java#L109.

The javadoc is clear about that.  We will add some clarity about that in the user guide.

Comment: Hi Jeff I merged the pull request and the test passes when I run via gradle. But when running in Intelij it fails even with annotation processing enable.

Comment: I would have to look at it to troubleshoot why your IntelliJ environment doesn't work.  Note that I improved the bean processor so it no longer limited to singletons.

Comment: Thank you Jeff, this is amazing.

Comment: @LuisTrigueiros, I was able to make IntelliJ successfully run the test by delegating  IDE build/run actions to gradle. Also Run tests using Gradle Test Runner.

Comment: @sofiaguyang You don't really need to delegate the IDE build/run actions to Gradle in order to make it work.  Instead you could simply enable annotation processors in the IDE (Build, Execution, Deployment -> Compiler -> Annotation Processors -> Enable annotation processing".  The only time you really need to delegate to Gradle is if you are using Kotlin and that is because of how kapt doesn't work in the IDE.

Comment: I do Micronaut dev work in the IDE almost every day and I don't configure my build to delegate to Gradle, except for projects that contain Kotlin artifacts.

Comment: @JeffScottBrown seems like you're right -- I may have just misconfigured something.

Comment: @JeffScottBrown I decided to have another look because I recall clearly that Luis's spock test failed when I tried it. When I said I may have been wrong, I was using my personal project to try things out. I realized that my project was all Groovy. For Groovy, AST is used instead of annotation processing -- no need to enable annotation and gradle runner. But for Luis's case, I tried again, and despite enabling the annotation processor, the test couldn't find the bean. What did work was enabling the gradle test runner -- didn't seem to matter whether annotation processor was enabled or not.

Comment: @sofiaguyang I can't reproduce the behavior you are seeing.  Things appear to work fine from here as long as I enable annotation processors in the IDE.  Not sure what might be going wrong there.  Sorry I can't be more help.